# Update MySQL Query that selects records with a certain non-unique value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for help creating a MySQL query. I have the following database table:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+
| option_type_id | option_id | sku         | sort_order | customoptions_qty | default | in_group_id | dependent_ids | weight |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+
|            552 |       137 | 13071727    |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            553 |       137 | 13071727B   |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           1 |               | 0.0000 |
|            554 |       137 | 13071727C   |       1000 | 1                 |       0 |           2 |               | 0.0000 |
|            555 |       137 | 13071727D   |       1000 | 1                 |       0 |           3 |               | 0.0000 |
|            556 |       138 | 13085350-1  |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            557 |       138 | 13085350-1D |       1000 | 2                 |       0 |           1 |               | 0.0000 |
|            558 |       138 | 13085350-1C |       1000 | 3                 |       0 |           2 |               | 0.0000 |
|            559 |       138 | 13085350-1B |       1000 | 2                 |       0 |           3 |               | 0.0000 |
|            560 |       139 | 13069547M   |       1000 | 20                |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            561 |       140 | 13084477-2  |        950 | 2                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            562 |       140 | 13084477-2B |        951 | 2                 |       0 |           1 |               | 0.0000 |
|            563 |       140 | 13084477-2C |        952 | 3                 |       0 |           2 |               | 0.0000 |
|            564 |       140 | 13084477-2D |        953 | 0                 |       0 |           3 |               | 0.0000 |
|            565 |       140 | 13084477-2E |        954 | 2                 |       0 |           4 |               | 0.0000 |
|            566 |       141 | 13066533-1  |       1000 | 4                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            567 |       141 | 13066533-1B |       1000 | 5                 |       0 |           1 |               | 0.0000 |
|            568 |       141 | 13066533-1C |       1000 | 5                 |       0 |           2 |               | 0.0000 |
|            569 |       141 | 13066533-1D |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           3 |               | 0.0000 |
|            570 |       142 | 13071674    |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            571 |       142 | 13071674D   |       1000 | 1                 |       0 |           1 |               | 0.0000 |
|            572 |       142 | 13071674C   |       1000 | 2                 |       0 |           2 |               | 0.0000 |
|            573 |       142 | 13071674B   |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           3 |               | 0.0000 |
|            574 |       142 | 13071674E   |       1000 | 4                 |       0 |           4 |               | 0.0000 |
|            575 |       143 | 13071667    |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
|            576 |       143 | 13071667B   |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           1 |               | 0.0000 |
|            577 |       143 | 13071667C   |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           2 |               | 0.0000 |
|            578 |       143 | 13071667D   |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           3 |               | 0.0000 |
|            579 |       143 | 13071667E   |       1000 | 0                 |       0 |           4 |               | 0.0000 |
|            580 |       144 | 13066295    |       1000 | 1                 |       0 |           0 |               | 0.0000 |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

What I'd like to do is **update** all the rows where `in_group_id` = 0, to add an `A` to the end of the `sku`. However I'd only like to do this on rows that **do not** have a unique `option_id` value.

For example, you can see that the row with `option_id` = 139 is the **only** row with this `option_id` value, so I'd like to **exclude** this row from being updated.

Basically this is a list of product options, some products have multiple options each with it's own SKU. However for these products that have multiple options there is an 'A' missing from the end of the 1st option's SKU, and I'd like to add it. But I don't wish to add an 'A' to products that only have 1 option. I hope this makes sense.

If someone could advise on the MySQL statement that could achieve this, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will do what you want :

```
UPDATE Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM Table1
        GROUP BY option_id
        HAVING count(*) = 1) t1 ON t1.option_type_id = Table1.option_type_id
SET table1.sku = concat(table1.sku,'A')
WHERE table1.in_group_id = 0 AND t1.option_type_id is null
```

See SQL FIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d08e/1/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query  to limit to only those option_ids that have a count of 1.

```
UPDATE  YourTable T
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT option_id
                ,COUNT(option_id) as opt_count
        FROM    YourTable T1
        GROUP BY
                option_id
        ) SQ
ON      SQ.option_id = T.option_id                
SET     T.sku = CONCAT(T.sku,'A') 
WHERE   T.in_group_id = 0 
AND     SQ.opt_count = 1
```